# Unoconv/libreoffice command line convert very slow

Tags: php, exec, libreoffice, unoconv

I'm using unoconv or libreoffice to convert documents, `odt->pdf`, by `PHP exec()`. This process is very fast on one of my server (about 1s).
Now I have another, much faster server, and this process is taking almost 20s! 
And it's with the same, small 20k files. I googled, I set the same configuration, and can't find any clues - what could be the reason?

Result is the same when i'm using unoconv, and libreoffice directly. When `starting unoconv --listener` first, first conversion can be made in about 20 seconds. Then all conversions are fast again.

It seems that simple starting Libreoffice is taking a lot of time, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the answer was simple...

In processlist I can see:

```
root      4197  1.1  0.2 1112580 66436 pts/2   Sl+  20:20   0:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --invisible --nocrashreport --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nologo --norestore --accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext
```

It seems that LibreOffice is using IP and port for some internal communications, so I turned off the firewall (iptables) and it worked fine - from 20 seconds to 1 second!!

At the end I found, that IP6 can not be blocked on firewall for local connections, and that's what was causing the problem.

After I add this rule to `iptables.v6` configuration file, everything is working fine:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```